# How to invoke constructor when processing .json object

Tags: java, json, constructor, gson

I am parsing a JSON file using `Gson.fromjson`

The Java Object which I am reading into is structured as follows:

```
int amount;
String name;
HashMap<String,Integer> someMap;
OtherDataObject[] data;
```

The json file however has only the int & String values.
The result is that my HashMap and OtherDataObjects in the 'data' array are not initialized.

Is there a way to invoke the constructor during this process?

If I can invoke the constructor I can also initialize the array and HashMap.

Is it conceptually wrong to initialize objects from a JSON file/string that contains only part of the members? Would it be better practice to parse into a Pojo made specifically for the JSON being read and use that to compose a larger object(with the Pojo as a member)?